# How do I ignore a directory in mod_rewrite - tried ^min - [L,NC]

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get it so that anything inside of the folder `min` does not get my rewrite rules.

```
# Dispatcher wiring

#Add to stop the rules applying to the minify rules
RewriteRule ^min - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dispatch\.php$
RewriteCond /var/www/sexdiaries.co.uk/docroot%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /dispatch.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^x\.!dispatch\.php([^b]+)!dispatch\.php$ !dispatch\.php [L,NE]
```

The folder `min` is at the root of the folder so: `/var/www/sexdiaries.co.uk/min`

Comment: Your rule looks fine, and should work. Where are you putting these rules? Inside a htaccess file, or directly into the virtualhost section of your apache config files? If the latter, you should put a `/` in front of `min`. Also, your last line however doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: In the vhost. added the `/` in front of `min` and now it 404's, which is an improve of getting my templated files. But now i'm not sure what to do to troubleshoot, nothing in the log files. What do you thinks wrong with the last line?

Comment: was in my site sepcific error log. So, its navigating to `/docroot/min` I've got my `docroot` set to `/var/www/sexdiaries.co.uk/docroot` Guess I need to update everything and put `docroot` to `/var/www/sexdiaries.co.uk/` ?

Comment: Except for the first rule, do the rest of the rule-set in your question works or you are just testing it?

Comment: Ye, i can still navigate to any other page which doesn't start with /min... which is every other page ;)

Comment: Could you give some sample urls that start with `/min`?

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest this:

```
    <Directory /min>
         RewriteEngine Off
    </Directory>
```

...or something like that